# Screen recording has no sound (default ubuntu's tool)

Tags: gnome, sound, 22.04, screenshot, desktop-recording

When I switched to Ubuntu I started using the default snipping tool, which apparently it's called `screenshot`, although it looks really similar to gnome-screenshot, it looks a bit different. This is an image I found on the internet of the tool's GUI:

[image: Ubuntu's default screenshot and screencasting tool]

It works like a charm, however, the **recording function does not capture sound** that may be reproducing **on the background**. Is this the expected behaviour? If so, why implement a screen recording tool with no sound capabilities? Is there any config file I can tweak so it captures sound by default that I may be missing? I tried solving this before, but no luck so far. All I found is [this](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/screen-shot-record.html.en) official gnome article which happens to match working shortcuts.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS 64 bits

GNOME version: 42.5

Comment: Just a heads-up that the answer you accepted was generated via ChatGPT (which also explains why it was answered so fast ;-).  Since ChatGPT's training data is from 2020, it can't have any information about Ubuntu 22.04.  The existing answer will likely be deleted by a Mod based on the [current community consensus](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20185/ban-chatgpt-and-ai-generated-answers-on-ask-ubuntu).  Unfortunately, I don't have the answer for you, but maybe and hopefully there's still a way to accomplish this that someone will answer.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Oh ok! Thanks for letting me know. I read the community question on Meta about banning ChatGPT answers some days back. Definitely something to restrict.

Comment: It is indeed the default behavior that the GNOME Shell Screen Recorder does not capture the audio of your device.
However, you may try out one of the solutions highlighted [in this tutorial](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/05/record-desktop-with-sound-ubuntu-2204/).

Comment: @IndexOutOfBoundsException Yup, such a pity that Ubuntu's screencast software does not record audio, wish it did. I started using OBS again (used it on W10 before switching to Ubuntu), but I'll take a look at Kooha, thanks for sharing the tutorial.